# Passing props to components from MaterialBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I have used `MaterialBottomTabNavigator` for navigation. It is working fine when tabs are click strong texted on, but I have a button ( link ) in the home component screen. When that button is clicked it should go to the projects component.The button is in Home component (Touchable opacity) named See All.

This is my navigator (App.js)

```
import React from 'react';  
import { View } from 'react-native';  
import { createAppContainer , createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';  
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';  
import { Home , Projects , Gallery , Contact , Reviews , About }  from  './pages'; 


    const TabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(  
        {  
            Home: {
                 screen: Home,  
                 navigationOptions:{  
                    tabBarLabel:'Home',  
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (  
                        <View>  
                            <Icon style={[{color: tintColor}]} size={25} name={'ios-home'}/>  
                        </View>),  
                } 
            },  
            Projects: { screen: Projects,      
                navigationOptions:{  
                    tabBarLabel:'Projects',  
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (  
                        <View>  
                            <Icon style={[{color: tintColor}]} size={25} name={'ios-business'}/>  
                        </View>),  
                    activeColor: '#c42e00',  
                    inactiveColor: '#000',  
                    barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },  
                }  
            },  
            Gallery: { screen: Gallery,  
                navigationOptions:{  
                    tabBarLabel:'Gallery',  
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (  
                        <View>  
                            <Icon style={[{color: tintColor}]} size={25} name={'ios-image'}/>  
                        </View>),  
                    activeColor: '#c42e00',  
                    inactiveColor: '#000',  
                    barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },  
                }  
            },  
            Contact: {  
                screen: Contact,  
                navigationOptions:{  
                    tabBarLabel:'Contact',  
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (  
                        <View>  
                            <Icon style={[{color: tintColor}]} size={25} name={'ios-phone-portrait'}/>   
                        </View>),  
                         activeColor: '#c42e00',  
                         inactiveColor: '#000',  
                         barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
                }  
            }, 
            Reviews: {  
                screen: Reviews,  
                navigationOptions:{  
                    tabBarLabel:'Reviews',  
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (  
                        <View>  
                            <Icon style={[{color: tintColor}]} size={25} name={'ios-chatboxes'}/>  
                        </View>),  
                         activeColor: '#c42e00',  
                         inactiveColor: '#000',  
                         barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
                }  
            }, 

            About: {  
                screen: About,   
                navigationOptions:{  
                    tabBarLabel:'About',  
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (  
                        <View>  
                            <Icon style={[{color: tintColor}]} size={25} name={'ios-person'}/>    
                        </View>),  
                         activeColor: '#c42e00',  
                         inactiveColor: '#000',  
                         barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
                }  
            },  
        },  
        {  
          initialRouteName: "Home",       
          activeColor: '#c42e00',    
          inactiveColor: '#000',  
          barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },   
        },  
    );  

    const Nav =  createAppContainer(TabNavigator);       

    export default Nav
```

this is my Home component (Home.js)

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Dimensions , ScrollView ,ActivityIndicator ,Image ,Text , TouchableOpacity}  from 'react-native'; 
    import axios  from 'axios';
    import { Header , Statusbar , Carousel }  from '../common'; 

    import {Nav , Projects }  from '../pages';  
    var { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window"); 


    class Home extends Component { 

       constructor(props) {

          super(props);
          this.state = {
           layout: {
               height: height,
               width: width
           },
           sliders : [],
           projects : [],
           loader : false
        }
    }


 _onPressButton(){

       this.props.navigation.navigate('Projects');     

    }

    render(){

     return(

          <View   
             style={styles.main_container}
             onLayout={this._onLayout}     >




                 <View style={styles.project_text_container}>

                    <View>

                       <Text style={styles.text1}>Our Projects</Text>


                    </View>


                    <View>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>

                         <Text style={styles.text2}>See All</Text>

                    </TouchableOpacity>

                     </View>

                </View>   


             </View> 

            )

       }

    }

    const styles =   {

       main_container:{
           flex : 1,
       },

       project_text_container:{

          flexDirection : "row",
          marginLeft : 28    

       },

       text1:{

          fontSize : 20, 
          fontWeight : "bold",
       },

       text2:{

          marginLeft : 150,
          color : "#c42e00", 
          fontWeight : "bold",
          marginTop:5

       },

       image_style:{

          height : 180,  
          width : 150,

       }
    }  
    export { Home }
```

Comment: Please, show us some code, what you have tried, how you structured the navigator. Leaving it like this makes it impossible for us to even think about a possible solution

Comment: I have added code.Please check and let me know if there are any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is almost fine but your `_onPressButton` does not have access to the `this` of the current component. You have to either bind it or use arrow function.

For the `bind` you can do it both in the constructor:

```
   constructor(props) {

      super(props);
      this.state = {
       layout: {
           height: height,
           width: width
       },
       sliders : [],
       projects : [],
       loader : false
    }
      this._onPressButton.bind(this)
}
```

or the onPress directly:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this)}>
```

If you need to pass a param when you bind it on the on press you can simply do

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this, "params")}>
```

If you don't want to see the bind around your code (as you have to do it to almost every function) you can use arrow function that will auto-bind the function.

To use arrow function you need to simply change you function to:

```
_onPressButton = () => {

   this.props.navigation.navigate('Projects');     

}
```